# Will electrical discharge through a ground bar reach a lake?

Tags: ground

Will an electrical discharge through a ground rod that sits in the water table be conducted to a lake sitting 4 feet from the ground bar?

I have a newly installed breaker box feeding power to a dock. The breaker box is mounted on a pole approximately 3 feet from the lake. If I install the ground bar directly under the box I hit water approximately 24 inches underground. I guess I'm asking if that water is connected to the lake water or if the discharge would dissipate before reaching the lake water.

I want to be sure it will be safe for grandchildren to be swimming in the area if there is a discharge through the ground bar.

Comment: It's not insulated, so... of course it will. The discharge current will spread out radially from the grounding rod.

Comment: thank you . I assumed so

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a newly installed breaker box feeding power to a dock.  the breaker box is mounted on a pole approx 3 feel from the lake .  If I install the ground bar directly under the box I hit water approx 24 inches under ground.  I guess I'm asking if that water is connected to the lake water or if the discharge would dissapate before reaching the lake water,

Comment: I have a hard time seeing how this would be a problem.

Comment: I want to be sure it will be safe for grandchildren to be swimming in the area if there is a discharge through the ground bar

Comment: The discharge would most likely come from a lightning strike, and it is not safe to be swimming or wading in water when there is lightning. The usual rule is that everyone must get out of the water at the first flash of lightning or peal of thunder. And then wait at least 1/2 hour after the last such observation before getting back in.

Answer (score 2):

Electric shock drowning [is serious business](https://www.electricshockdrowning.org). You have every reason to fear it.  It absolutely can kill your family.

However, I hear you have already installed a subpanel 3 feet from water and only now are thinking about grounding rods. That suggests me that you might be DIYing, without adequate familiarity with the electrical codes. The codes are fair, sensible, and written in blood.  It is urgent that you follow them to the letter where a dockside installation is involved. StackExchange is happy to help you succeed.

### *Many* installation errors or defects can energize the ground rods.

For instance, one common installation blunder is to not run a ground wire from the house to dockside, on the logic that "a ground ROD is the same thing and will just do that job". Actually, if the neutral wire fails, the ground around the panel will be energized at line voltage, and that will create a voltage gradient through the water that will shock swimmers.

For instance, neutral and ground must be separated in the subpanel, neutral and ground wires must run separately back to supply, neutral must be insulated, and then Code legal grounding rods must be installed *also* and tied to the ground and not the neutral.

So if you're asking "can you make this all good with a ground rod" the answer is no. The installation must be correct in all other respects.

### I would move the subpanel well back from the water, and use GFCI breakers to supply dockside

I would go at least 30 feet from water's edge, and the reason is to give the grounding rods more space to dissipate current without creating a sharp voltage gradient at water's edge.

Then, I would use GFCI breakers or other devices to protect all circuits which go onward to dockside.  That way all the wiring that goes anywhere near the dock is fully GFCI protected.  So if a wire is punctured or chafes... fine, a person touches the hot wire, but as soon as 6 mA of current flows, the GFCI back at the panel goes "POP!" (a GFCI at the socket would do nothing in this case. With GFCI sockets the wiring to the socket is unprotected.)  GFCI is a silver-bullet solution if used as I say.

The minimum legal ground rods under NEC are two 8' long ground rods at least 6' apart.